# How to mock ProcessMessageEventArgs object to pass as a parameter in a method from a test method in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-4.0, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am writing a test method for below mention method -

Method in my concrete class -

```
public async Task ReadServiceBusMessage(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
 // Some code

}
```

-- In my test method-

```
public async Test_ReadServiceBusMessage()
{
        private Mock<ProcessMessageEventArgs> _eventArgs;

        **_eventArgs = new Mock<ProcessMessageEventArgs>(MockBehavior.Strict);**

         await concreteClassObj.ReadServiceBusMessage(_eventArgs.Object);

}
```

this object creation (highighted in bold) is giving below exception message

> Property ProcessMessageEventArgs.Message does not have a setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the message to the constructor.  For example:

```cs
Mock<ServiceBusReceiver> mockReceiver = new();

mockReceiver
    .Setup(receiver => receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(
        It.IsAny<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = ServiceBusModelFactory.ServiceBusReceivedMessage(
        body: new BinaryData("message"),
        messageId: "messageId",        
        /* << SNIP for brevity, more fields available >> */
);

ProcessMessageEventArgs processArgs = new(
    message: message,
    receiver: mockReceiver.Object,
    cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

More context and further examples can be found in the [Mocking Client Types](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample15_MockingClientTypes.md#for-the-servicebusprocessor) sample.